# Programmatically send a remote control event in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to trigger a remote control event such as `UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause` programatically. The application that I have in mind is a voice remote control application (even if it already exists) which receives the command "**Play**" and it simply generates the event `UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause`. Any app registered as the first responder for this event will get it. I.e. my app simply translates voice to remote control commands.

Ideas?

Comment: You can't send remote control events to other apps using the public iOS API.  It's probably not even possible with private APIs unless you jailbreak.  If you want an answer that requires jailbreaking, you should probably mention that in your question.

Comment: No, it should not require jailbreaking. If I can't send a remote control event - any pointers on how the "remote" app was built for apple TV? How would I go about building an identical app?

Comment: The Remote app doesn't need to send remote control events to other apps on the local device.  It sends messages to the AppleTV over WiFi.  You can also send messages to other devices on the WiFi using Bonjour and normal UDP and TCP sockets.

Comment: Yes, I guess I shouldn't have asked the "remote" app question in the same thread as the remote control events question. I guess this question no longer belongs in this thread but  my question now is "what does the app "remote" send to the apple tv when (say) it wants to "play")"  - is the protocol/the data that transits between the app "remote" and the apple TV public? If I want to send the play command to apple TV, what are the contents of my TCP packet? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to generate `UIEvent`s programmatically.

You can do it by using private API (google `synthesize UIEvent`). Some testing frameworks do that. Also, for testing, you can inject Apple's UI Automation framework into the application and use its method to generate events (mostly touch events, headers available on github).

However, synthesizing events is something you can't do in an Appstore application. If you need to do that, it's a bad design.